# #1305 - FUNCTION clubmc.DATEADD does not exist [ Mysql ]

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select all the date + 3 month from my table, i write this query

```
select DATEADD(month, 2, `creatdate_time`) AS DateAdd FROM app_user
```

but the console shows me this errors:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION clubmc.DATEADD does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
select date_add(`creatdate_time`, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AS DateAdd FROM app_user
```

Documentation [Date add](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To add months in MySQL you can use:

```
select DATE_ADD(`creatdate_time`, interval 2 month) AS DateAdd
FROM app_user
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCcfDqPxCu2m2RBuX3nP2B/0).